# Upgrade from 18.10 to 20.04 options

Tags: upgrade, 18.10, 20.04

I've just spent ages trying to work out how to upgrade from 18.10 to 20.04 now it's almost out. I realize I was on an end of life and would have to upgrade through another end of life and this appeared prohibitively difficult and the advice is to reinstall

I have however just achieved it by just updating my /etc/apt/sources.list from `cosmic` to `focal` - I had to remove the EOL source I was using to the standard

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe
```

And then

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
```

It gave an error about a pre-removal script for whoopsie, but I managed to sort this with

```
dpkg --purge --force-all whoopsie
apt install whoopsie
```

I realized `force-all` isn't great but I couldn't find another way around it, and whoopsie appears to have been able to report itself after reinstall!

and then carried on with where I was
When I try `do-release upgrade`, it says no new version as it seems to have performed the upgrade okay - `lsb_release -a` gives `20.04`

Is there anything else I need to do? Have I been extremely lucky?
Just wanted to put it out there in case anyone else was trying the same

Comment: I have just tried the same procedure, in the same conditions, but I couldn't get past the `whoopsie` error because `systemctl` always gave an error. I had to **reboot** after `apt dist-upgrade`. After that I was able to `apt --fix-broken install` and finish the upgrade without removing any packages.

Comment: Similar here. The whoopsie-thingy workaround did not work. Upgrade stopped at around 20%. Reboot didn't work either, not even on the command prompt. Had to be a reboot -f.
Then everything came back and I could continue with the apt upgrade without any further ado.

Comment: It worked pretty much flawlessly for me too. I didn't face the whoopsie issue at all, but before that I had an error when it was trying to change `chromium-browser` from package to snap. Tracking down the problem I found that the underlying issue was that it could not do a `systemctl daemon-reload` which eventually was solved by running `kill -TERM 1` which reloads the daemon manually. After that I run `apt --fix-broken install` and it finished successfully without any more issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly try upgrading that way. It's a perfectly valid Debian way (indeed, it's the original way).

However, the upgrade path from 18.10 directly 20.04 has not been tested, so we generally don't provide support for it if you encounter unexpected problems.

- Consider running `sudo apt autoremove` to remove packages that were orphaned by the dist-upgrade. Read the list of proposed removals carefully!
- Consider marking your calendar for late April and late October if you want to stick to the 6-month interim releases of Ubuntu. That way, you won't get caught out with an EOL release again. Alternately, on 20.04, you can change to LTS releases and upgrade every 2 years (mark your calendar for that, too.)
- For in-band release-upgrades by most users, we recommend `do-release-upgrade` over the method you used. `do-release-upgrade` has fewer places for the user to make a mistake. Your release-upgrade was, of course, out-of-band since 18.10 has been EOL many months.